# Can the bounty notice custom message be made available in the question history and/or in the awarded bounty tooltip?

Tags: feature-request, bounty, revision-history

The use case is recovering bounty context.

For example, assume a user awards bounties for answers that have "I like turtles" in it.

Or a user provides more context in the bounty notice, like a code example.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on Meta.SE: [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110003/348196)